# How can i make pandas version 18.0 store sets

Tags: python, pandas

How can I make pandas version 18.0 store sets

I'm working with python pandas 
I use the code below and i get different result on pandas version 18.0 and pandas version 17.0

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([{'a':set()}])

    a
0  {}
```

while in 17.0 the result is

```
         a
0  set([])
```

Answer (score 2):

The data is stored the same - just the print `repr` seems to be different.

```
In [83]: import pandas as pd
    ...: data = pd.DataFrame([{'a':set()}])

In [84]: data
Out[84]: 
    a
0  {}

In [85]: data.iloc[0,0]
Out[85]: set()
```

Comment: how would you fix the repr, without wrapping the DataFrame

Comment: You could make an issue if you'd like - the original change was [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11215/files)